# Where can I download the Portuguese language patch?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The Brazilian server of World of Warcraft will start today.  Does anyone know the place to download the Portuguese Language patch for my WoW client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When available, the Portuguese Language Pack will likely be on this [download page](https://us.battle.net/account/download/).  The one for Spanish is already there, so it's likely that Portuguese will be there as well.

You may also want to keep an eye on the [WoW Brazil FAQ page](http://us.blizzard.com/pt-br/company/events/wow-brazil.html), as that's likely to have information relevant to your question as it is available.

Answer (score 1):

When available, With starting your WOW-Launcher, it will download automatically the missing files, who is "Portuguese Language Pack" at your purpose.